# Reviewer Stats - have the link point to activity --> reviews tab

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

In the suggested edit page <sup>([live example](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/164199))</sup>

> [image]

there is a *Reviewer Stats* section with a link to the reviewer's profile: <sup>([live example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/899271/pratapchandra))</sup>

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/ID/NAME
```

Instead of a link to the default page (summary) have that link point to the activity tab, *reviews* filter - [example with above user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/899271/pratapchandra?tab=activity&sort=reviews):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/ID/NAME?tab=activity&sort=reviews
```

Maybe even have the suggested edit we came from be highlighted.

Seems like a better fit to me, and it will save time, as when going to the profile from that location it usually means we want to see more reviews that that user performed.

Comment: Hi, Shadow, I was about to request the same and shamelessly plugged the snapshot I was preparing. Also added URL samples to make the issue clearer. Hope you don't mind & feel free to rollback.

Comment: @brasofilo all good, but the FHRC is weird. :D (pink-ish?)

Comment: Flipa! Yes, now is pure `R`, hopefuly :)